# Import Conan packages to a disconnected network

Tags: conan

I'm working in an organization with no internet connection. What is the correct way to "import" Conan packages into the organization? Assume I have a way just to transfer files into the organization's network.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is running an [Artifactory instance](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/artifactory/artifactory_ce.html). You can download it from [Conan Download](https://conan.io/downloads.html) page. It's free, and can be used for business without restrictions.

Why is it the best choice? As you need to share your packages in your company, you need to centralize its distribution. Conan packages are not a simple zip file which can be sent by email (ugly), they have ID, checksum validation, revision, version ... So Artifactory organizes your packages and distribute them correctly.

But if you can't run [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/), or your need is too small for it, you still can try [Conan Server](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/remotes.html#conan-center). It works like a simple server, and is very feature limited, but good enough for small experiments.

Comment: Hi @uilianries, we do have Artifactory in our company, and the intent is to use it. The question is how to import existing packages from the conan-center into our internal Artifactory instance?

Comment: You are looking for Remote Repository, read Artifactory doc: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Conan+Repositories However, you will need internet connection for caching, otherwise, you will need to download somehow, and upload manually.